# DateTime "invalid per syntax" in LDAP pwdLastSet attribute

Tags: datetime, ldap, openldap, ldif

I'm trying to add a `pwdLastSet` attribute to my LDAP test user. I've created this ldif file:

```
dn: cn=test,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: passwordLastSet
add: pwdLastSet
pwdLastSet: 199412161032Z
```

When I try to `ldapmodify`

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f add-pwdlastset.ldif
```

I get a error message:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "cn=test,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
   additional info: objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

I've looked up chapter 3.3.13 "Generalized Time" in [RFC4517](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4517.txt) which provides the following examples:

```
  Examples:
     199412161032Z
     199412160532-0500

Both example values represent the same coordinated universal time:
10:32 AM, December 16, 1994.
```

As you might notice, I even copy-pasted the first example to my ldif file, to no avail. Could someone enlighten me what's wrong with this syntax?

Forgot to mention that I also tried with a unix timestamp

```
pwdlastset: 1643988710
```

which yields the same error message.

---

**Update:**

When I change the `changetype` from `add` to `modify` and remove the `objectClass` (as suggested in EricLavault's answer) like this:

```
dn: cn=test,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: pwdLastSet
pwdLastSet: 1643988710
```

I get the following error:

```
$ sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f add-field.ldif 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=test,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17)
    additional info: pwdlastset: attribute type undefined
```

When I then add the `objectClass` definition again like this

```
dn: cn=test,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
objectClass: passwordLastSet
add: pwdLastSet
pwdLastSet: 1643988710
```

I get the following error:

```
$ sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f add-field.ldif 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
ldapmodify: modify operation type is missing at line 3, entry "cn=test,dc=example,dc=com"
```

I tried some other modify operation types (`replace`), but nothing worked. Still stuck here.

Comment: If you're working with Active Directory, [these docs](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Pwd-Last-Set%20attribute) suggest that you can't set that attribute to anything other than `0` or `-1`. That seems to be confirmed [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9c3caa80-9e97-4808-96a8-5af696aaa7b3/pwdlastset-possible-to-change-?forum=winserverDS). If you're not working with AD, you'd need to check the syntax definition for that attribute in your LDAP server.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I'm working with OpenLDAP and even trying to add `0` returns the same error. I'll try to find out how to get the type definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing (which is not obvious at first glance) is that `ldapmodify` allows to *add* entries, in which case you set `changetype: add`.

You want to *modify* an existing entry, so you should set `changetype: modify` in order to `add: pwdLastSet` or (replace|delete).

If you also need to add `objectClass: passwordLastSet` to the entry or other changes, note that every operation (add|replace|delete) must be separated, eg.

```
dn: cn=test,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: objectClass
objectClass: passwordLastSet
-
add: pwdLastSet
pwdLastSet: 199412161032Z
```

Also if I'm not wrong, the [`PwdLastSet`](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Pwd-Last-Set%20attribute#section-Pwd-Last-Set+attribute-Implementations) attribute is only implemented in Active Directory.

If you are using OpenLDAP you should probably use the [`PwdPolicy`](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/PwdPolicy) auxiliary class (ppolicy overlay).

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try this!

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work (see my update above), thanks anyway!

Comment: @digijay Yes, I did not understand the first time that you actually want to add pwdLastSet _and_ the objectclass. I updated the answer accordingly, though as mentioned this attribute is only implemented on AD. If you are on OpenLDAP and struggle to tweak your password policy, I suggest reading this [page](https://tylersguides.com/guides/openldap-password-policy-overlay/) which covers all the basics. Also, I think you should not directly set this attribute, as the equivalent of `pwdLastSet` for OpenLDAP is `PwdChangedTime` and is supposed to be an operational attribute maintained by the server.

Comment: It seems that you are right with this. Thanks for the clarification and your time, I really appreciate it!